# Cómo obtener de un Map, una lista de sus claves ordenadas por sus valores

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Tengo un `Map` y necesito obtener una lista de sus claves, y que esta esté ordenada según los valores del `Map`. Ej:

```
Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("Lunes", 8.5);
map1.put("Jueves", 2.0);
map1.put("Martes", 5.4);
```

Lo que quiero es obtener una lista `List<String> claves` que contenga `"Lunes", "Martes", "Jueves"` de forma que estén ordenados y aparezcan como -> `"Jueves", "Martes", "Lunes"`. He conseguido crear la lista con el siguiente código, pero no ordenarla: `List<String> claves = map1.keySet().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Las claves y los valores no están repetidos y prefiero que la solución sea con Java 8 y trabajando con streams. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido lo que buscaba con el siguiente código:

```
List<String> claves = new ArrayList<>();
map1.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getValue())).
        forEach(x -> claves.add(x.getKey()));
```

Primero creo la lista que quiero devolver. Luego utilizo el método `EntrySet()` para operar con pares de `clave-valor` y lo convierto en `stream` para ordenarlo según el `valor`. Y por último, itero para añadir a la lista final "claves" las `claves` ordenadas.